# SQLITE3 - Why is counting 'null' records over a 100x faster than counting 'not null' records in an indexed column?

Tags: sqlite

I have a table with 300,000 rows, with an indexed column being either a large text block or NULL. Currently around 250,000 rows are NULL, with the other 50,000 rows filled with text.

`c.execute('SELECT count(*) FROM table WHERE indexed_column IS NULL)`

This does a row count in under one second.

`c.execute('SELECT count(*) FROM table WHERE indexed_column IS NOT NULL)`

`c.execute('SELECT count(*) FROM table)`

Both of these statements take around 180 seconds each to do their counts.

Why is there such a huge speed discrepancy for identifying NULL values vs NOT NULL? Is there a faster way to count NOT NULL values?

The Query plan for IS NULL:

```
(0, 0, 0, 'SEARCH TABLE table_name USING INDEX column_index (column=?) (~10 rows)')
```

Query plan for IS NOT NULL:

```
(0, 0, 0, 'SCAN TABLE table_name (~500000 rows)')
```

Comment: Show the output of [EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN](http://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html) for both queries.

Comment: Okay I added the plan. It seems obvious now that the search for IS NOT NULL  is not using the index and is searching row by row. Why is that? Is there a way to force the query to search using the index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are searching a table for a single value, the query optimizer estimates the result to be much smaller than when searching a table for all values but a single one. In the latter case, if the estimate is correct, looking up rows through an index would be slower than just doing a table scan.

In your case, the default estimate is wrong because most of the rows actually have NULL.
To get actual statistics about the distributions of values in the index, run [ANALYZE](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_analyze.html).

Also consider updating SQLite; newer versions should always detect that the index is a covering index.

Comment: But if the database can count not nulls so quickly why does it need to go through the whole table? Shouldn't it be able to go through the index until it hits null and then stop? This would iterate through only 50,000 rows instead of the full 300,000. Is there a way I can do this manually? Like a quick way to count rows without actually scanning over the table row by row (which is really slow). If I did that I could subtract the number of NULL values to get NOT NULL.

Comment: I don't know how exactly your old version of SQLite works. I believe you won't have this problem with a current version.